# gqlgen - DirectiveResolver not exported by package generated

Tags: go, graphql, gqlgen

I am new to GraphQL, gqlgen library. Tried running `go run github.com/99designs/gqlgen init` command but getting `validation failed: packages.Load: C:\Users\Aylin\Desktop\gqlgen-tutorial\graph\prelude.resolvers.go:19:44: __DirectiveResolver not exported by package generated` error. This is the first step of the project setup and is not supposed to cause any errors. Anyone had the same problem and knows how to fix it? Thanks

Comment: I have the same issue.
`schema:
- schema.graphql
exec:
  filename: ../../src/http_app/gql/generated/generated.go
  package: generated

model:
  filename: ../../src/model/models_gen.go
  package: model

resolver:
  layout: follow-schema
  dir: ../../src/http_app/gql
  package: gql
  filename_template: "{name}.resolvers.go"
  type: Resolver

autobind:
  - framegork/src/model

omit_slice_element_pointers: true`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I took this one and I've resolved it.
Change version for "github.com/vektah/gqlparser/v2" in your go.mod file.
From:

```
go 1.16
require (
    github.com/99designs/gqlgen v0.13.0
    github.com/vektah/gqlparser/v2 v2.2.0
)
```

To:

```
github.com/vektah/gqlparser/v2 v2.1.0
```

Delete **prelude.resolvers.go** after that.

Comment: Worked for me, thanks! Any idea about why this happens in the first place, or when they're going to fix this?